# Derivative of an multivariable Inverse Function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, inverse-function

The function is 
$$f(x)=\int_{2}^x \sqrt{1+t^2}dt $$
Using the formula
$$\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(a))} $$
I get 
$$f'(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2} $$
but do I now need to integrate the above derivative in order to find f(x), or find the inverse of the derivative?

Comment: You are right, but it's better to get it immediately.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg which part am i right about?

Comment: About the answer. I posted it. See now.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are trying to use the inverse function derivative formula.  What you are looking for is a direct consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: There's nothing multivariable about this function. The title is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left(\int\limits_a^xg(t)dt\right)'=g(x),$$ which gives the answer immediately:
$$f'(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}.$$

Comment: So the inverse of that would be $\sqrt{x^2-1}$?

Comment: @Eric Brown You don't need this. The property, which I wrote is true for all continuous function $g$.

Comment: well I didn't put it in the post but I need to prove that the function is one-to-one and find $(f^{-1})(0)'$

Comment: @Eric Brown It's really another problem. We got that $f'(x)>0$, which says that $f$ it's one to one. Now, use that $f(2)=0.$